# Two-Dimensional Array with JSON data - Data is downloaded, but I can't access it (?)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, multidimensional-array, retrofit

So, I am creating a little trivia game for learning purposes, but I ran into a problem.

First, I had a specific Android Fragment obtaining the data from JSON, and I will simply use that data on the callback method and display it on TextViews and Buttons. Everything was working fine, however, every time I returned to that fragment, the same questions would be there. So I decided to handle that in a better way outside of the callback method.

The problem here is that apparently my Arrays are either null or their lengths is zero. Which is weird, because according to my LOG, data is being passed to those arrays on the callback method.

Here's my full fragment code. Thanks!

```
public class GameFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView txtQuestion;
private Button btnAnswer1;
private Button btnAnswer2;
private Button btnAnswer3;
private Button btnAnswer4;

private Questions[] gameQuestions;
private Questions[] animeQuestions;
private Questions[] techQuestions;
private Questions[] movieQuestions;
private Questions[][] gameCategories = new Questions[4][];

int correctAnswer = -1;

private TransparentProgressDialog progressBar;
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;


Callback cb = new Callback<MyApiData>(){

    @Override
    public void success(MyApiData myApiData, Response response) {

        gameCategories[0] = new Questions[myApiData.getCategory()[0].getQuestions(0).length];
        gameCategories[1] = new Questions[myApiData.getCategory()[1].getQuestions(1).length];
        gameCategories[2] = new Questions[myApiData.getCategory()[2].getQuestions(2).length];
        gameCategories[3] = new Questions[myApiData.getCategory()[3].getQuestions(3).length];

        //gameCategories = new Questions[][] {gameQuestions, animeQuestions, techQuestions, movieQuestions};

        for(int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < gameCategories[i].length ; j++){
                gameCategories[i][j] = myApiData.getCategory()[i].getQuestions(i)[j];
                //Log.d("GameFragment", "gameCategories[i][j] - gameCategories["+i+"]["+j+"]: " + gameCategories[i][j].getQuestion());
            }
        }

        //displayQuestion();
        progressBar.dismiss();
        displayQuestion();
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        Log.d("GameScreen", "Callback failed!");
    }
};

public GameFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false);

    txtQuestion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);

    btnAnswer1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer1);
    btnAnswer2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer2);
    btnAnswer3 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer3);
    btnAnswer4 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer4);

    btnAnswer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View view) { checkAnswer(view); } });
    btnAnswer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View view) { checkAnswer(view); } });
    btnAnswer3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View view) { checkAnswer(view); } });
    btnAnswer4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            checkAnswer(view);
        }
    });

    handler = new Handler();
    progressBar = new TransparentProgressDialog(getActivity(), R.drawable.loading_spinner);
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };

    //launchRingDialog();
    //RestClient.get().getQuestions(cb);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}


public void launchRingDialog() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            try {
                Log.d("Thred", "Try");
                progressBar.show();
                RestClient.get().getQuestions(cb);
                //Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            //progressBar.dismiss();
        }

    }).start();
}


public void checkAnswer(View v){

    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnAnswer1:
            if(correctAnswer == 1){
                feedback(true, btnAnswer1);
            }else {
                feedback(false, btnAnswer1);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnAnswer2:
            if(correctAnswer == 2){
                feedback(true, btnAnswer2);
            }else {
                feedback(false, btnAnswer2);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnAnswer3:
            if(correctAnswer == 3){
                feedback(true, btnAnswer3);
            }else {
                feedback(false, btnAnswer3);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnAnswer4:
            if(correctAnswer == 4){
                feedback(true, btnAnswer4);
            }else {
                feedback(false, btnAnswer4);
            }
            break;
        default: txtQuestion.setText("Error");
            break;
    }
}

public void feedback(Boolean correct, Button btn){

    if(correct){
        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        btn.setText("CORRECT!");
    }else{
        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        btn.setText("WRONG!");
    }

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //displayQuestion();
}

public void displayQuestion(){

    Random randomizer = new Random();

    int randomQuestion;
    int category = GTMain.choosenCategory;

    if(category == 5){
        category = randomizer.nextInt(4);
    }

    randomQuestion = randomizer.nextInt(25);

    Log.d("displayQuestion", "Before if statements");

    if(gameCategories != null && gameCategories.length != 0) {
        Log.d("displayQuestion", "First if");
        if(gameCategories[category] != null && gameCategories[category].length != 0){
            Log.d("displayQuestion", "Second if");

            txtQuestion.setText(gameCategories[category][randomQuestion].getQuestion());
            correctAnswer = gameCategories[category][randomQuestion].getCorrectAnswer();
            Log.d("displayQuestion()", "correctAnswer: " + correctAnswer);
            btnAnswer1.setText(gameCategories[category][randomQuestion].getAnswers().getA1());
            btnAnswer2.setText(gameCategories[category][randomQuestion].getAnswers().getA2());
            btnAnswer3.setText(gameCategories[category][randomQuestion].getAnswers().getA3());
            btnAnswer4.setText(gameCategories[category][randomQuestion].getAnswers().getA4());
        }
      }

   }
 }
```

**PS:** On my main activity, I check to see which fragment should be loaded. If it's the fragment that contains the components to display the questions and answer (the one from the code above), I call the following method: `gameFragment.launchRingDialog();` (and yes, I have created an instance of my GameFragment fragment before calling that method!)

Answer (score 0):

When onResume() is called, your RestClient.get().getQuestions(cb) is still running in background, and your call displayQuestion(), so of course nothing is shown.

Can you put displayQuestion() inside success() of your callback?

```
Callback cb = new Callback<MyApiData>(){

    @Override
    public void success(MyApiData myApiData, Response response) {
        ....

        for(int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < gameCategories[i].length ; j++){
                ...
            }
        }
        displayQuestion();

    }
    ....
};
```

I would also suggest you to remove displayQuestion() in onResume() method.

Comment: that does make it sort of work, but now there's two problems: I am telling it to display the info even before an user selects a category (which means the correct answer, and question itself is all wrong). And that takes me back to whenever I open that fragment, it still has what was there the last time (that's why I was trying to call displayQuestion within the onResume method)

Comment: That's great! Since you only want to call displayQuestion() after the users have select a category AND you want to wait until the API call has finish, I would suggest you to display a Loading Dialog before you call RestClient.get().getQuestions(cb) and then dismiss the Dialog in onSuccess() method. This way, your users are not allow to interact with your app while you're fetching your data. Then you would want to put displayQuestion() method inside your button onclicklistener.

Comment: I tried some things but I could not get it to work... I'm stuck! If I put RestClient.get().getQuestions(cb) on the onCreateView method, it's called once, and nothig ever updates after (but at least it works once) - if I put anywhere else, it's like it was never called, and it doesn't work. 
I am updating the code with the little Progress Dialog thing... Any ideas of why that's happening? Ps: I have a fragment called categories, there is where the user choose a category, and then this fragment is loaded to display the question and answers.